# Summing results of a table

Tags: list-manipulation, summation

I have a simple table:

```
example1 = Table[N[x^(x/r), 5], {r, 1, 10}, {x, 1, 10}]
```

I want to create a new table `Table[Sum[N[x^(x/r), 5], {r, 1, k}],{k,1,10},{x,1,10}]`, but using the data from `example1` rather than having to recalculate `x^(x/r)` and then sum the results - clearly advantageous when the table gets bigger.

I assume it's a simple thing to do, but I can't figure it out. I input

```
example2 = Table[Sum[example1, {r, 1, k}], {k, 1, 10}, {x, 1, 10}]
```

but the result is a table of tables.

How do I do this? Is it even possible?

Comment: Oddly, no. For example at `{x,k}->{2,3}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Accumulate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Accumulate.html) on `example1` to get the same table produced by `Table[Sum[N[x^(x/r), 5], {r, 1, k}],{k,1,10},{x,1,10}]`:

```
example3 = Accumulate[example1]
```

> {{1.0000, 4.0000, 27.000, 256.00, 3125.0, 46656., 8.2354*10^5, 
>     1.6777*10^7, 3.8742*10^8, 1.0000*10^10},
>    {2.0000, 6.0000, 32.196, 
>     272.00, 3180.9, 46872., 8.2445*10^5, 1.6781*10^7, 3.8744*10^8, 
>     1.0000*10^10},
>   {3.0000, 7.5874, 35.196, 278.35, 3195.5, 46908., 
>     8.2454*10^5, 1.6782*10^7, 3.8744*10^8, 1.0000*10^10},
>    {4.0000, 
>     9.0016, 37.476, 282.35, 3203.0, 46923., 8.2457*10^5, 1.6782*10^7, 
>     3.8744*10^8, 1.0000*10^10},
>   {5.0000, 10.321, 39.409, 285.38, 3208.0,
>      46931., 8.2459*10^5, 1.6782*10^7, 3.8744*10^8, 
>     1.0000*10^10},
>   {6.0000, 11.581, 41.141, 287.90, 3211.8, 46937., 
>     8.2460*10^5, 1.6782*10^7, 3.8744*10^8, 1.0000*10^10},
>    {7.0000, 
>     12.800, 42.742, 290.11, 3215.0, 46942., 8.2461*10^5, 1.6782*10^7, 
>     3.8744*10^8, 1.0000*10^10},
>    {8.0000, 13.989, 44.252, 292.11, 3217.7,
>      46946., 8.2461*10^5, 1.6782*10^7, 3.8744*10^8, 
>     1.0000*10^10},
>    {9.0000, 15.156, 45.694, 293.96, 3220.2, 46949., 
>     8.2462*10^5, 1.6782*10^7, 3.8744*10^8, 1.0000*10^10},
>   {10.000, 
>     16.304, 47.085, 295.70, 3222.4, 46952., 8.2462*10^5, 1.6782*10^7, 
>     3.8744*10^8, 1.0000*10^10}}

```
example3  == Table[Sum[N[x^(x/r), 5], {r, 1, k}],{k,1,10},{x,1,10}]
```

> True

Comment: Not quite sure what I'm supposed to do with this. I'm a complete novice... I'm after a table that uses `example1` as its source data.

Comment: OK, I'm still missing something. What would the expression be to create a new table using `example1`? you're showing me a test rather than the table... I know I'm being dumb. I appreciate your patience.

Comment: Fab. Thanks. Sorry to have been so slow.

Comment: @RichardBurke-Ward, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82253/discussion-between-richard-burke-ward-and-kglr).

Comment: I feel embarrassed now, but can I ask one more question? If I want to summarise `Accumulate[example1]` so that the resulting table sums each row but only shows (say) each second row, so we have (for example) `{k,1,11,2}`... is there a way of doing that?

Comment: @RichardBurke-Ward, does `Total/@Accumulate[example1][[;;;;2]]` give the desired result.

Comment: Actually, no (but thank you!). What I was hoping for was a row for `k=1`, then a row for `k=3` which is the sum of `k=1->3`, then an entry for `k=5` which is the sum of `k1->5` and so on...

Comment: @Richard, how about  `Accumulate[example1[[;;;;2]]]` or `Accumulate[example1][[;;;;2]]`?

Comment: That seems to be adding `k=1 + k=3 + k=5`... But it misses out `k=2`, 'k=4`, etc.